# How is ほか used as a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

What does `ほか` mean when it is used in a sentence like this: [situationA] ほか, [situationB]"

Specifically I would like a little help clarifying the following sentence:

> 事件事故が減った`ほか`、緊急時以外の通報の減少が主な要因とみられる。

I am familiar with  ほか in other situations, but I'm not sure how it's used here. As far as I can figure out, it's either *along the lines* of "It's not that the number of accidents has decreased, but..." or "The number of accidents has decreased, but more importantly...".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means "besides". It confirms the existence of [situationA], and states that there is another [situationB]

Your example may be translated as:

> Besides the decrease of the number of emergencies(accidents, ...), the decrease of the calls when there is no emergency is an important reason.